# How can I derive a formula that produces a set of numbers per index?

Tags: algorithms

For example, assuming I am using the set of natural numbers $\mathbb{N}^* = \mathbb{N} \cup 0$ as my domain.

I want to create an algorithm such that at each index value $i$, I output a set.

For example,

- $0$ maps to $\{1,2,3,4\}$
- $1$ maps to $\{5,6,7,8\}$
- $2$ maps to $\{9,10,11,12\}$

How might I go about deriving the function needed to produce the desired codomain?

Answer (score 1):

Just map $n$ to $\{4n + 1, 4n+2, 4n+3, 4n+4\}$.

Comment: I‘d like to accept your answer, but I was mostly interested in how to derive the formula so that I don‘t have to ask next time ;)

Comment: @JonathanKomar I don't know how to explain such a formula in general other than 'basic math'. Check out [modulo](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modulo_operation), perhaps that helps you.

Comment: This is similar to programming by example. I don't think there is a general process to derive formulas from examples. I guess you have to observe the pattern (throughout the examples) and express it formally in mathematical terms.